# Using Navigation drawer and tab layout in same activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I know this has been asked frequently, but I haven't found what I exactly need.

What I'm aiming to is the following:

1. One activity, the main layout should contain three tabs using tab layout and view pager.
2. This same layout must have Drawer layout and navigation view.
3. I want the 3 tabs in the main layout to be in a coordinator layout as I want it to coordinate as I scroll in my list.
4. When I select something from the drawer layout I want the whole screen (except the toolbar) to be replaced with a fragment depending on what was chosen.

I have tried:

1. This [link](https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/) but what he does is separate the tab layout from the toolbar, making the toolbar no coordinating I guess. i.e when he swipes through the list the toolbar won't get hidden.

I have tried this code as well(No coordinator layout yet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
```

But when I choose an item from the drawer, I replace the fragment on the frame layout, this is what I get:
[The new layout contains a text view only. And as you can see, the frame layout doesn't cover the whole screen, but it is placing the text view on top of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DEsB.jpg)

EDIT: When I choose an item in the drawer, I want the tabs to be hidden or disappear and only the toolbar should remain

Comment: I think you have to replace your fragment in viewpager